# Swing - Adding line to exiting Panel doesn't show up

Tags: java, swing

I have a JPanel with points drawn at start. I am trying to add lines between these points, as I traverse between these points. But lines do not show up. If I use repaint, previous drawing goes away. Below is my code. Do I need to refresh something in the drawLine code?

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    doDrawing(g);
}
//works fine
private void doDrawing(Graphics g) {
    g.drawLine(x, y, x, y);
}

//called later from outside, lines do not show up on Panel
public void drwaLine(Point p1, Point p2) {
    Graphics g2d = getGraphics();
    g2d.drawLine(p1.getX(), p1.getY(), p2.getX(), p2.getY());
}
```

Comment: This is why you shouldn't use `getGraphics`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I use repaint, previous drawing goes away.

Yes, because the whole component is repainted again and the first thing a panel does is paint its background to clear all the old painting.

See [Custom Painting Approaches](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for the two common ways to do painting:

1. Use a List to hold the objects you want to paint
2. Use a BufferedImage.